# How to display a message when a user is passing a specific location from a map with Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, geofire

I want to add 5 markers (city locations) on a map and every time a users is passing nearby, I want to display the user a message: `You have just passed the first location, then second location and so on`.

How can I achieve this? I this even possible with Firebase?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Comment: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/06/geofire-20.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since the question is *rather unspecific about the details*, here's a rather broad answer of how I would personally approach solving the problem:

So from what I understand the problem is split up into the following parts:

- Displaying markers on a map
- Listening to user location
- Comparing user location to marker locations
- Displaying messages

**Displaying markers on a map**

I'm assuming that you were thinking about using the Google maps API to do so, therefore I would recommend looking at the following: [Adding a map with a marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map-with-marker)

**Listening to user location**

Listening to user location is explained in the following document: [Location Strategies](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html). Multiple approaches are listed on how to get the users location, matching your specific needs.

**Comparing user location to marker locations**

I personally would recommend using your [Noodle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain) over here. I can't do all the thinking for you, but somehow you must have the location coordinates of the markers stored and accessible for comparison with the user's location updates. I would also keep track of whether a 'checkpoint' has been visited or not already in order to avoid displaying messages excessively.

**Displaying messages**
Last but not least, displaying of the messages. I would use [Toasts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) to display to the user that they have passed a checkpoint. A smart way to do this would be to have this happen in the onLocationChanged method that you're going to have to override for listening to location updates, and simply display a toast when you're comparing locations method tells you so.

*I personally do not see the need to add firebase to this, since no storing or getting of data from a DB is necessary. Everything can be done locally.*

**P.S. don't forget to mark this as the right answer if it ended up helping you!**